# Python import and reload misunderstanding

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

The original title was: 'Numpy array: 'data type not understood''. Turns out, the problem was my misunderstanding of Python as an interpreted language.

I have this very simple module 'rtm.py':

```
import numpy as np
def f():
    A=np.array([[1.0,0.5],[0.0,1.0]])
```

But when I run it in IPython:

```
import rtm
rtm.f()
```

I get this error:

```
      1 import numpy as np
      2 def f():
----> 3         np.array([[1.0,0.5],[0.0,1.0]])

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Which part in the documentation didn't I understand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What happens if you run A=np.array([[1.0,0.5],[0.0,1.0]]) in IPython?

Comment: No problem at all. After importing numpy as np, of course.
I get the feeling it's something stupid like saving the file in an inappropriate place.

Comment: Have you tried specifying data-type?  np.array([[1.0,0.5],[0.0,1.0]], dtype='float')

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Now it runs. I think it had something to do with IPythons way of importing stuff.
 
I come from Matlab. When I change something in a script and run it again, it re-interpretes the script. Whereas when I change a python script and run it again in IPython it apparently does not re-interprete, but uses the old version unless I quit and restart.
Is this intentional? I thought Python was an interpreted language as well?

Comment: You have to use reload(module) instead import. See the answer.

Comment: IPython has an `autoreload` extension to make this behave more like matlab, because it confuses a lot of people switching to Python. [Docs are here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to made external changes in modules visible inside interpreter session you have to use reload instead import:

Python 2

```
import rtm
# some change in rtm.foo has been made
import rtm 
rtm.foo() # Old version of rtm.foo is called

reload(rtm) # You have to reload module ([docs][1])
rtm.foo() # Now you can call new version of rtm.foo
```

Python 3

```
...
from imp import reload
reload(rtm)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. I changed the title to prevent confusion.